# LESSCSS and @keyframes

Tags: css, less, css-animations

Has anyone had issues with LESSCSS and `@keyframes` or `@-ms-keyframes`? It compiles the CSS fine for `@-webkit-keyframes`, `@-moz-keyframes` and `@-o-keyframes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are whitelisted, `-ms` is missing. `keyframes` should work: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L988

There is an open request for a fix: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/498

The common workaround is to put keyframes in a separate `.css` file that you import - files with a .css extension are not parsed by LESS.

Comment: Yeah I thought this was the case, it's a shame as I'd like to use LESS classes in the keyframes.

Comment: LESS should use a different syntax for variables. :(

Answer (score 1):

Keyframes generation seems to be very compicated in LESS, that is why appeared different hacks and tools such as:

- https://github.com/kuus/animate-me.less
  A bit complicated mixin generating both keyframes and animation with a single call. Accepts both animated elem selector and keyframes css content as strings. Up to 10 steps in keyframes
- https://github.com/thybzi/keyframes
  My tool inspired by animate-me and other solutions. Generates keyframes only. Animation needs to be applied separately - which allows to apply multiple animations to a single element, and also the same keyframes to multiple elements. More actions needed to create keyframes, but uses true css/less way to generate their style (so you can use variables, operations, functions and mixins there). Up to 16 keyframes steps

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide some background information about using these tools. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I updated my comment, providing some info of those tools